# I want to use errant with spacy v3...errant is not working with spacy v3

Tags: python, spacy

errant wants 'en' module to work that is, errant.load('en') and there is no 'en' module in spacy v3

I tried to lower the spacy to version 2 then there was still the same problem.

Comment: Please show your code and the actual, exact error message and traceback.

Comment: @AKX [x] Couldn't link model to 'en' 
There is no 'en' model on spacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Errant with Spacy v3 by just making changes or editing the Errant class.

[Reference](https://github.com/chrisjbryant/errant/commit/e53a16a083a64a95cffffde56828c4d4ddab62ad)